# Remove duplicate objects based on the same key from array and add their value to the object that is left

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider the following array of objects in javascript

```
const array = [
  { 10205: 2 },
  { 10207: 3 },
  { 10205: 2 },
  { 10207: 1 }
]
```

I would like to have it converted to

```
array = [
  { 10205: 4 },
  { 10207: 4 }
]
```

Comment: I recommend showing the code that you have tried so far as SO isn't a code writing service.

Comment: There are lots of duplicates on "grouping". [Like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57877891/how-to-group-array-of-objects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const array = [{ 10205: 2 }, { 10207: 3 }, { 10205: 2 }, { 10207: 1 }];

const newArray = [];
array.forEach((element) => {
  const elementKey = Object.keys(element)[0];
  const foundIndex = newArray.findIndex((_) => Object.keys(_)[0] === elementKey);
  if (foundIndex >= 0) {
    newArray[foundIndex] =
        {[elementKey]: newArray[foundIndex][elementKey] + element[elementKey]};
  } else newArray.push(element);
});
console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Please use reduce function.

```js
    const array = [
      { 10205: 2 },
      { 10207: 3 },
      { 10205: 2 },
      { 10207: 1 }
    ]
    
    console.log(Object.values(array.reduce((acc, el)=>{
        Object.keys(el).map((key)=>{
            acc[key] = {
                [key]: (acc?.[key]?.[key] ?? 0) + el[key],
            }
        })
        return acc;
    }, {})));
```